# Default value in migration turns into SQL error

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to update my code from Laravel 5.8 to Laravel 6.0. When I attempt to migrate the database, there is a  SQL syntax error.

**Migration**

```php
Schema::create('stocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('initial_price');
    $table->unsignedInteger('quantity');
    $table->unsignedInteger('price');
    $table->string('language')->default("EN");
    $table->string('state', 2)->default('MT');
    $table->string('idArticleMKM')->nullable(); //idArticle from mkm
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('EN'), `state`
>   varchar(2) not null default ('MT'), `idArticleMKM` varchar(1023)' at
>   line 1 (SQL: create table `stocks` (`id` int unsigned not null
>   auto_increment primary key, `product_id` int unsigned not null,
>   `initial_price` int unsigned not null, `quantity` int unsigned not
>   null, `price` int unsigned not null, `language` varchar(1023) not null
>   default ('EN'), `state` varchar(2) not null default ('MT'),
>   `idArticleMKM` varchar(1023) null, `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug recently and only temporarily introduced:

- Original PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/29878
- Reverted: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/29943
- Docs PR: https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/5466

Upgrade to 6.0.3 to fix it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v6.0.3